# Why is a subclass in Java an instance of the super class but not assignable to it?

Tags: java

For a very basic example:

```
public class Human {
    //human stuff
}

public class Developer extends Human{
    //developer stuff
}
```

Why is `Developer` an instance of `Human`, but the class `Developer` is not assignable to `Human`?

```
Developer dev = new Developer();
System.out.println(dev instanceof Human); //true
System.out.println(Developer.class.isAssignableFrom(Human.class)); //false
```

But in addition to this: `Human` is assignable to `Developer`.

```
System.out.println(Human.class.isAssignableFrom(Developer.class)); //true
```

In normal English I would say that a `Developer` object is assignable from a `Human` class, not the other way around.

Comment: `To` and `From` are different things

Comment: What would that mean? That every human has the same set of skills ("methods") as developer? Nah,  this has to be false :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you suppose there is a function assignableTo, this is that you say but assignableFrom is reverse:

> The java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom()  determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the **same as, or is a superclass or superinterface** of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.

You can learn more enter [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_isassignablefrom.htm)

Answer (score 4):

A `Developer` **is-a** `Human`, but not every `Human` **is-a** developer.

Inheritance imposes an [is-a relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) on its children.  This means that a child can always be identified by their parent class, but a parent isn't proven or demonstrated to be identifiable by their child.

In a nutshell, this is what `isAssignableFrom` is demonstrating; you're wondering if a `Human` is assignable from a `Developer`, which isn't true.  That sort of assignment would be `Developer dev = new Human();`, which only works the other way 'round (i.e. `Human human = new Developer();`).

Answer (score 3):

```
Human.class.isAssignableFrom(Developer.class)
```

in English means: you can assign to a variable of the `Human` class an object of the `Developer` class.

Answer (score 1):

> In normal English I would say, that a developer object is assignable from a human class, not the other way around.

And the problem is your usage of the words "object" and "class" here. It should be: a `Human` *variable* is assignable from a value of type `Developer`.

You assign a value *to* a variable *from* evaluating an expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Human human = new Developer()
```

But you cannot do:

```
Developer developer = new Human()
```

In logical terms, every developer is a human not every human is a developer.

If you had a class `QaEngineer` that would inherit from `Human` you won't want this to be allowed:

```
Developer developer = new QaDeveloper()
```

or this:

```
Developer developer = (Human) new QaDeveloper()
```

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation of the method

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.[...]

So basicly the method returns, if the parameter class provided is the same class or interface, or a subclass or subinterface of the Class it was invoked on.

```
Developer.class.isAssignableFrom(Human.class) // False, Developer is not a superclass of Human


Human.class.isAssignableFrom(Developer.class) // True, Human is a superclass of Developer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to think it like this:

```
   Human.class.isAssignableFrom(Developer.class)  //true;
```

means you can assign a developer object in reference of Human.

```
    Developer.class.isAssignableFrom(Human.class) //false;
```

means you can not assign an object of Human class (parent) in the reference of Developer class (child).

 
The core rule is that: You can assign an object of child to reference of parent, not the other way round.

Hope it helps.